# Show that $ \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{x}{x^4+1} e^{-ikx}dx=- \pi ie^{-k/ \sqrt{2}}\sin(k/ \sqrt{2}) $ for $k>0$

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-transform, residue-calculus

So since $k>0$ we consider the poles in the lower half plane, which are $e^{-i\pi/4}$ and $e^{-3i\pi/4}$

The residue for the first one is $\frac{e^{-i\pi/4}e^{-ikx}}{4e^{-3\pi i/4}}=\frac{1}{4}e^{(\pi/2-kx)i}$

The residue for the second one is $\frac{e^{-3i\pi/4}e^{-ikx}}{4e^{-9\pi i/4}}=\frac{1}{4}e^{(3\pi/2-kx)i}$.

So I get that the integral = $-\frac{2\pi i}{4}(e^{(\pi/2-kx)i}+e^{(3\pi/2-kx)i})$

At this point I'm stuck on where to go from here, since the powers of $e$ are not the same so I don't know how we can get the sin bit?

Comment: You forgot the $e^{-ikx}$ term when you computed the residues. Obviously the residues should not depend on $x$.

Comment: @Klaus thank you, so I now get the integral to be $\frac{\pi}{2i}e^{-k/\sqrt{2}}(e^{i\pi/2+k/\sqrt{2}-ike^{i\pi/4}}+e^{3i\pi/2+k/\sqrt{2}-ike^{3i\pi/4}})$. I can't see how we get the sin part from here, given that we have exponentials of exponentials?

Comment: Try using $e^{i\pi/4} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(1+i)$ next. Similarly for the other exponentials that are just complex numbers.